# C# regarding enum methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hey everybody I'm new to C# and I'm having a few issues. I'm currently doing an assignment for school and I'm really stuck on this part. I've staring at it and googling things for hours and I'm having any luck. I have included below what I have so far.

The directions aren't that good.

"Create a public enum CharacterState for the 4 image states: Attacking, Defending, Idle, and Dead. 
Now create a member variable state to hold the character state and a public property State with a get 
and set. For now, fill in the default behavior of get and set to return/set the value of state."

Any help would be greatly appeciated! Thank you

```
namespace WPFBattle
{
    class CharacterImage: System.Windows.Controls.Image
    {
        public enum Attacking{

        }

        public enum Defending{

        }

        public enum Idle{

        }

        public enum Dead{

        }
        public ImageSource IdleImageSource { get; set; }
        public ImageSource AttackingImageSource { get; set; }
        public ImageSource TakeDamageImageSource { get; set; }
        public ImageSource DeadImageSource { get; set; }

        protected void UpdateImageSource()
        {
            switch (State)
            {
                case CharacterState.Attacking:
                    this.Source = AttackingImageSource;
                    break;
                case CharacterState.TakeDamage:
                    this.Source = TakeDamageImageSource;
                    break;
                case CharacterState.Dead:
                    this.Source = DeadImageSource;
                    break;
                case CharacterState.Idle:
                default:
                    this.Source = IdleImageSource;
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            UpdateImageSource();
            base.OnRender(dc);
        }

        public CharacterState State
        {
            get { return state; }
            set
            {
                state = value;
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    UpdateImageSource();
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you have 4 empty enums instead of just one with 4 values.

Comment: What is CharacterState in your code?

Comment: And i'm still not sure what exactly is your question.

Comment: Oh okay, I just fixed that enum part. It works now, thank you

Comment: can you answer your question so others can benefit as well?

Comment: @firmfiasco do you by any chance have the entire project? I could use some help on it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with your enum.

> Create a public enum CharacterState for the 4 image states: Attacking, Defending, Idle, and Dead ...

From your code, you have created a single enum for each state. Enums are useful for defining options, in your case, you are supposed to have an enum that defines the state of your character.

```
public enum CharacterState {
    Attacking,
    Defending,
    Idle,
    Dead
}
```

> ... Now create a member variable state to hold the character state and a public property State with a get and set.

```
public class Character {

    public Character()
    {
        State = CharacterState.Idle;
    }

    private CharacterState state; //-Member variable (private)

    public CharacterState State 
    {  get
       {
            return state; // note the casing in State and state
       }  
       set
       {
           State = value;
       }
}
```

Then you can access the current state of your character through its State property.

```
var character = new Character();
CharacterState state = character.State; // returns Idle.
// or set it
character.State = CharacterState.Attacking;
Console.WriteLine($"Take cover! character is {character.State}");
//- logs "Take cover! character is Attacking"
```

Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: thank you very much for your response! I fixed the enum part but I'm still a little confused on the "Now create a member variable state to hold the character state and a public property State with a get 
and set. " part. I'm not sure exactly how to fix that issue.

Comment: I updated the answer with some comments. Note that `state` is the member variable, that can only be updated from the Property `State`, note the different casing and `private / public` modifiers. `state` can only be accessed from within the class while `State` *encapsulates* it. This means you can read and write `state` by accessing the public property `State`.

Answer (score 1):

Your enum is declared wrong. This is what you want.

```
enum CharacterState
{
    Attacking,
    Defending,
    Idle,
    Dead
}

class CharacterImage 
{

    private CharacterState state;
    public CharacterState State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set
        {
            if (state == value)
                return;

            state = value;               
        }
    }
}
```

You can also write your property as..

```
public CharacterState State { get; set; }
```

This compiles the same code as the above property, except maybe for the value comparison part.

```
if (state == value)
    return;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the statement -as you wrote- says: *Create a public enum for 4 image states*. This, is just **one object with 4 possible values**. Created, then use a property / field member to manage the internal value. Maybe, it comes like this:

```
    namespace WPFBattle
{
    public enum CharacterState{
        Attacking = 1,
        Defending = 2,
        Idle = 3,
        Dead
    }

    class CharacterImage: System.Windows.Controls.Image
    {

        public CharacterState _state;

        public ImageSource IdleImageSource { get; set; }
        public ImageSource AttackingImageSource { get; set; }
        public ImageSource TakeDamageImageSource { get; set; }
        public ImageSource DeadImageSource { get; set; }

        protected void UpdateImageSource()
        {
            switch (_state)
            {
                case CharacterState.Attacking:
                    this.Source = AttackingImageSource;
                    break;
                case CharacterState.TakeDamage:
                    this.Source = TakeDamageImageSource;
                    break;
                case CharacterState.Dead:
                    this.Source = DeadImageSource;
                    break;
                case CharacterState.Idle:
                default:
                    this.Source = IdleImageSource;
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            UpdateImageSource();
            base.OnRender(dc);
        }

        public CharacterState State
        {
            get { return _state; }
            set
            {
                _state = value;
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    UpdateImageSource();
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum CharacterState {
    Attacking,
    Defending,
    Idle,
    Dead
}

public class Character {

    public Character()
    {
        State = CharacterState.Idle;
    }

    private CharacterState state; //-Member variable (private)

    public CharacterState State 
    {  get
       {
            return state; // note the casing in State and state
       }  
       set
       {
           State = value;
       }
}
```